# How to parse ffmpeg progress real time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, popen

So I was struggling with this problem a long time last night and finally figured it out so I wanted to post here in case someone ran across the same issue.

The goal is to parse the output of FFmpeg so that it would run in a Sidekiq worker and save progress and duration to an ActiveRecord model so I could get a progress bar in the UI by polling the database.

How do I parse ffmpeg `duration` and `time` real-time without waiting for the process to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. How to parse output real-time in ruby?
2. Since FFmpeg writes progress output on one line, how do you get that output?

For the first one I looked at the ruby Open3 module and [this article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html) was particularly helpful. The gist is this:

```
require 'open3'
cmd = "bash my_long_running_command.sh"
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  stdout.each do |line|
    # this will print as stdout is being written to the stream real-time
    puts line
  end
end
```

Now this works well for many commands and all but not with FFmpeg. FFmpeg is weird in that it writes it's progress and output to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`.

Not only that but as I finally noticed the line delimiter of FFmpeg is not `\n` as it is in most bash commands but rather `\r` which is how it is able to edit the progress inline. Now that we know that the only updates are the stream and the delimiter, which can be overridden in the `each` method as the first argument.

```
require 'open3'
cmd = "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 ... output.mp4"
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  duration = 0
  progress = 0
  stderr.each("\r") do |line|
    next unless (line.include?("time=") || line.include?("Duration:"))
    if duration == 0
      if line =~ /Duration:\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{1,2})/
        duration = $1.to_i * 3600 + $2.to_i * 60 + $3
      end
    end 

    percentage = if line =~ /time(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/
      progress = $1.to_i * 3600 + $2.to_i * 60 + $3
      (progress.to_f/duration.to_f) * 100
    end

    puts "#{percentage}%"
  end
end
```

You can also use a gem that I found that does something very similar called [stremio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg) that I sadly found after I already implemented my solution. If you would like to do the same thing as above, just do:

```
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new('input.mp4')
duration = movie.duration
movie.transcode('output.mp4', options_as_a_string) do |progress|
  percentage = (progress.to_f/duration.to_f) * 100
  puts "#{percentage}%"
end
```

Comment: These useful comments could be fed back to the FFMpeg maintainer. I imagine such behavior (stderr and \r) is a bit unconventional to most people.

Comment: it basically outputs logs to stderr so that its stdout can be "piped" to other programs more easily, FWIW...